# pandas plot x axis labels overlapping

Tags: python, pandas

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
#code here

df = pd.DataFrame(items) #items is a list of dictionaries
counts =df.groupby('Merchant')['Merchant 1'].count().sort_values(ascending=False)counts2 =df.groupby('Merchant 2')['Seller'].count().sort_values(ascending=False)
total = counts.add(counts2, fill_value=0)
plt.ylabel('Number')
plt.xlabel("Merchant")
plt.title('Merchants Overview',color='b')
total.plot(kind='bar')
plt.xticks(rotation='horizontal')
plt.savefig("ex")
```

the provides correct "bars" but the text is over lapping in the x-axis

[image: plot output]

another quick question how can I sort the bars from highest to lowest.

I checked this [Pandas plot hide some x-axis labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48932345/pandas-plot-hide-some-x-axis-labels),also [x axis label in plot overlaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29104081/x-axis-label-in-plot-overlaps)
This is my first question,please be nice.

Comment: The correct way is to use the `rot=` parameter: `total.plot(kind='bar', rot=...)` as shown in the duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to change:

```
total.plot(kind='bar')
plt.xticks(rotation='horizontal')
```

to

```
total.sort_values(ascending=False).plot(kind='bar')
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
```

Output:

[image]

Or:

```
counts.sort_values(ascending=False).plot(kind='bar', color='darkblue')
plt.xticks(rotation=25)
```

Output:

[image]

If you really insist on horizontal label, consider horizontal bar:

```
counts.sort_values(ascending=False).plot(kind='barh', color='darkblue')
# plt.xticks(rotation=25)
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Does this make the x label vertical (in your image)? I want to keep them horizontal

Comment: Yes, It is much better but isn't there a way to space out the bars so the text takes it space (widening the spaces of bars or sth like that)

Comment: In that case, try playing with figsize by putting `plt.figure(figsize=(20,5))` before any plotting/labeling. But the label can be too small to read.